# Tamil Font problem in Android device

Tags: localization, fonts

I'm developing a Tamil web app (using PhoneGap) where I use unicode to display the Tamil language. The problem is, it is working fine in Android Emulator and in web (Firefox), but the fonts are not displaying in a Galaxy S device. I'm sure that I have used the following in my HTML file

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```

I really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: What version of the OS?

Comment: For potential Close voters: This is not necessarily a development issue. Whether a device/OS supports a particular font/language is on-topic here.